# Why I should add '&' before the parameter which is an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, function, c++11, reference, iterator

```
unordered_map<int, string>::iterator findElement(unordered_map<int, string> &intString, int index){
    return intString.find(index);
}
```

If I don't add the `&` before the `intString`, the code will crash.

Comment: do you know what the `&` means?

Comment: get the address?

Comment: `&` has 2 distinct meanings in different contexts.

`int *p = &i` is getting the address of `i`. `int &n = i` is a reference. Here, you're doing the latter

Comment: I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&` in the type for the function-parameter `intString` means that the function gets a reference to the passed argument, instead of a copy of it.

Thus, the iterator which is returned from `.find()` and which it returns in turn will point into the passed argument, instead of being a dangling iterator pointing somewhere into a no longer existing copy.

And accessing destroyed objects, especially if the memory was re-purposed, can have all kinds of surprising results, which is why it is called *Undefined Behavior (UB)*.